# Linear arrangement algorithm

Tags: javascript

I am not sure if title is correct.

I have few labels which have set their positions in y scale in range:

```
range = [0, 100px]
```

for example: 5 labels in positions:

```
positions = [5px, 6px, 8px, 72px, 76px]
```

Now I want my algorithm to correct these positions to not let them be closer than 10px to each other and do minimal corrections.

I am expecting calling my function like this:

```
result = calculateNewPositions(range, positions, min(10px, 100px / positions.length))
```

and result in this case should be:

```
[0px, 10px, 20px, 69px, 79px]
```

What is name of this alghoritm or how to implement that?

Comment: That's not a sorting algorithm, more of a recursion algorithm.. What have you tried ?

Comment: I did not expect this to be a sorting alghoritm.
I not trayed yet anything. Becaouse I have no idea how to do this efficiently.

Comment: @Pogrindis *cmd+F, "sort", 0 results from the question and title*

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks, with the mention of `arrangement` there is some ambiguity.

Comment: This raises questions on how you want the arraignment  to be set though too.  Just look at how flexbox had to add rules for specifying justifying the content with space arround and space between.  The behaviour is not well laid out in your question

Comment: @JosephMarikle I dont want to use flex. I am operating in SVG element.
I just need alghoritm which can fix that positions like I said.

Comment: Just for the first two items (5px, 6px) You could either add room to the right or left of each.  You seem to set the first one to 0px and second one to 10px, but that's pretty arbitrary.  Why not `5px, 15px, 25px`? Edit: obviously flex is not an option.  I'm using it as an example of how someone had the same questions you should have when determining how to space content in a similar environment.  You will need to factor in similar logic for your issue.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I forget to pass to this function also range which is [0, 100px]
Let me fix my question

Comment: @Pogrindis Sorry.  Just poking fun. You are correct.

Comment: I dont know how to edit main post.

`range = [0, 100px]
positions = [5px, 6px, 8px, 72px, 76px]
result = calculateNewPositions(range, positions, min(10px, 100px / positions.length))

=> [0px, 10px, 20px, 64px, 74px]`

Comment: @gkucmierz it should be [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36722361/edit).

Comment: it used here the term [dispersing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532147/dispersing-numbers-in-a-javascript-array/29535300#29535300)

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks! The question and desired results are much more clear now!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm that should work pretty well for most cases, and tries to make as minimal amount of adjustments as necessary from the original values.

1. Iterate through each pair of elements.
2. If the space is not large enough, move them apart from each other by 1, making sure not to violate the range.
3. Repeat until all the elements have enough space between them.

And here is a sample implementation:

```
function calculateNewPositions(positions, minSpacing, rangeMin, rangeMax) {
  var temp = positions.slice(0);
  var madeChange;
  do {
    madeChange = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length - 1; i++)
      if (temp[i + 1] - temp[i] < minSpacing) {
        if (temp[i] > rangeMin) { temp[i]--; madeChange = true; }
        if (temp[i + 1] < rangeMax) { temp[i + 1]++; madeChange = true; }
      }
  } while (madeChange);
  return temp;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/aaxmuw2t/

Example Result: [0, 10, 20, 69, 79]

Note that this algorithm is very simplistic and may not always yield the best result for really complex arrays with lots of close numbers.  For example, if you input `[33, 34, 35, 36]`, you get `[19, 29, 40, 50]`, which has an extra unnecessary space.

Comment: for this input: `[95, 94, 92, 28, 24]` it should return that output: '[100, 90, 80, 31, 21]'

Comment: @gkucmierz: My algorithm assumes the numbers are sorted in ascending order as a precondition, since that was true for the only use case you provided.  It should be easy to handle numbers in descending order - just reverse it first, run the algorithm, and reverse again, and you get the expected result.  I think you should be able to handle that :)

Comment: You are right @mellamokb it is working in that case also: https://jsfiddle.net/aaxmuw2t/3/
But there are many cases when this code will not work as I expect.
I am currently working on another function.

Comment: @gkucmierz: Unfortunately I think solving this problem truly optimally is NP-hard.  So you're going to need some sort of heuristic that works for your common use cases.  Good luck! :)

Comment: @gkucmierz: I'd be interested to know for the sake of curiousity.  Can you provide a handful of the many cases that did not work as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

```
calculateNewPositions = function(positions, minDelta) {
   var newPositions = [0]
   positions.slice(1).forEach(function(pos, index) {
     var delta = positions[index + 1] - positions[index]
     newPositions.push(newPositions[index] + Math.max(delta, minDelta))
   })
   return newPositions
}
```

https://tonicdev.com/lipp/pos-diff

Comment: Something is wrong with this function. It is not working correct with my input.

Comment: the array must not contain the px stuff. [5px, 6px] ---> [5,6] did you try the link? isn't this what you are describing?

Comment: No, look at your result. res[1] and res[2] are overalapping

Comment: It returns now: [0, 10, 20, 84, 94]
I need [0, 10, 20, 64, 74] in this case

Comment: where is this 64 coming from? the original diff is 72px - 8px = 64px. 64px diff on 20px is 84px. don't you want the diff to remain the same as long as it is not smaller minDelta?

Comment: I get [0, 10, 10, 64, 10] at the moment.

Comment: that was the previous version... when you reload do you still get that?

Comment: I am sorry @lipp it should be: `[0px, 10px, 20px, 69px, 79px]`

`69px = (76px + 72px) / 2 - minDelta / 2 = 74px - 5px = 69px
79px = (76px + 72px) / 2 + minDelta / 2 = 74px + 5px = 79px`

Comment: no problem seems like @mellamokb has your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally did something like this:

```
var fixPositions = function(range, pos, delta, strict) {
  var i;
  var leftSpaces = [];
  var halfDelta = strict ? delta / 2 : 0;
  delta = Math.min(delta, (range[1] - range[0] / (pos.length + (strict ? 0 : 1))));

  // calculate all spaces that are greater than delta
  leftSpaces.push(Math.max(pos[0] - range[0] - halfDelta, 0));
  for (i = 1; i < pos.length; i++) {
    leftSpaces.push(Math.max(pos[i] - pos[i-1] - delta, 0));
  }
  leftSpaces.push(Math.max(range[1] - pos[pos.length-1] - halfDelta, 0));

  // save indexes of big spaces
  var nonZeroSpacesIdx = [];
  leftSpaces.map(function(space, i) {
    if (space > 0) {
      nonZeroSpacesIdx.push(i);
    }
  });

  // sort indexes by spaces sizes (start from smaller)
  nonZeroSpacesIdx.sort(function(a, b) {
    return leftSpaces[a] - leftSpaces[b];
  });

  // loop until spaces sum are greater than range
  var spacesSum = Infinity;
  while (nonZeroSpacesIdx.length > 0 && spacesSum > 0) {
    spacesSum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < nonZeroSpacesIdx.length; i++) {
      spacesSum += leftSpaces[nonZeroSpacesIdx[i]];
    }
    var missingDiff = (spacesSum + (pos.length - 1) * delta + halfDelta * 2) - (range[1] - range[0]);

    if (missingDiff <= 0) {
      break;
    }
    // find min diff which can be substracted from all spaces
    var minDiff = Math.min(missingDiff / nonZeroSpacesIdx.length, leftSpaces[nonZeroSpacesIdx[0]]);
    for (i = 0; i < nonZeroSpacesIdx.length; i++) {
      leftSpaces[nonZeroSpacesIdx[i]] -= minDiff;
    }
    // remove index of first space if its equal zero
    if (leftSpaces[nonZeroSpacesIdx[0]] <= 0) {
      nonZeroSpacesIdx.shift();
    }
  }

  // reconstruct new positions
  var newPos = [];
  newPos.push(range[0] + leftSpaces[0] + halfDelta);
  for (i = 1; i < leftSpaces.length - 1; i++) {
    newPos[i] = newPos[i-1] + leftSpaces[i] + delta;
  }

  return newPos;
};

// result should be from range: [5, 95]
console.log(fixPositions([0, 100], [5, 6, 8, 72, 76], 10, true));

// result should be from range: [0, 100]
console.log(fixPositions([0, 100], [5, 6, 8, 72, 76], 10, false));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fcwu1oyu/14/

Its not giving exact same values for my input, but it does the job for my pie charts:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A work in progress solution

The code pushes two too close couples appart with one on each side. This is symetrically and results in sometimes to far pushed values, which can be corrected.

```js
function disperse(values, threshold, range) {
    var delta = Array.apply(null, { length: values.length }).map(function () { return 0; }),
        converged = false;

    while (!converged) {
        converged = true;
        delta = delta.map(function (d, i, dd) {
            if (i < dd.length - 1 && dd.length > 1 && values[i + 1] + dd[i + 1] - values[i] - d < threshold) {
                converged = false;
                dd[i + 1] += 1;
                return d - 1;
            }
            return d;
        });
    }
    converged = false;

    // try to minimise difference
    while (!converged) {
        converged = true;
        delta = delta.map(function (d, i) {
            var space;
            if (i < delta.length - 2) {
                space = values[i + 1] + delta[i + 1] - values[i] - d;
                if (d < 0 && space > threshold) {
                    converged = false;
                    return d + space - threshold;
                }
            }
            return d;
        });
    }

    // respect lower range
    delta.reduce(function (r, d, i, dd) {
        if (values[i] + d < r) {
            dd[i] = r - values[i];
            return r + threshold;
        }
        return values[i] + threshold + d;
    }, range[0]);

    // respect upper range
    delta.reduceRight(function (r, d, i, dd) {
        if (values[i] + d > r) {
            dd[i] = r - values[i];
            return r - threshold;
        }
        return values[i] + d;
    }, range[1]);

    return values.map(function (v, i) {
        return v + delta[i];
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(disperse([5, 6, 8, 72, 76], 10, [0, 100]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(disperse([5, 6, 7, 8, 72, 76], 10, [0, 100]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(disperse([24, 28, 92, 94, 95], 10, [0, 100]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be the exact identical logic to mine, except that you aren't properly checking the range (0 to 100)...  Try the example OP posted under my answer: `24,28,92,94,95`.  Your code seems to return `21,31,83,94,104`, but 104 > 100.

Comment: if so, then i wrote it [a year before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532147/dispersing-numbers-in-a-javascript-array/29535300#29535300) you. :)

Comment: the last value is not in range. this is a prerequisite, that all values must in the range before.

Comment: i would let it open, because this problem needs some attention.

Comment: Erm... all the values in `24,28,92,94,95` are in range.  *Your code* is generating the value of 104 when it gets that starting list.

Comment: i see `result: 0,10,20,69,79,90,100`, which is in range. the 100 is just to proove the algorithm.

Comment: Sorry,, I guess I didn't explain myself very well :)  Maybe this will help: https://jsfiddle.net/7th90daa/.  Notice that the input values are all inside the range, but your code spits out a result outside the range (104).  Make sense?