# Make the distance between values in javascript array equal between each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a list of numbers inside an array, lets say for example:

```
var ArrayValues = [1, -2, 3]
```

This list of around 20-30 values, is being used in a graph, so when the graph is being drawn, if those values are different between each other, the graph goes up and down, not going up consistently with each value. So what I would like is that between each number there is the same amount so that the graph shows a continuous growing line, instead of a line that goes up and down at some points.

Can this be achieved with plain javascript? A function maybe to normalize the values within an array ?

So the above array should be output something like:

```
var ArrayValues = [0.6, 0, 1];
```

Making the distance between values more equal between each other.

Thanks !

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: But... the whole point of showing values is to have these points represented. IDK what you expect a line graph to do except to go 'up and down'. Continues growing line is just one of the possibilities with a chart, if your values are there to support that, but you are representing values, not faking data

Comment: @Dellirium correct, its sort of faking the data at some point, but that doesn't affect the end result at any point.

Comment: @mplungjan Yes I did, I saw some normalization in one of the answers, but wanted it to do it with plain Javascript with a function already made for that?

Comment: @Leo are you trying to make a line of best fit or something? There are statistical formulas for that.

Comment: @ADyson Yes I'm trying to make the line just go up between each point, never to make it go down within any point in the array.

Comment: What are you using to draw the graph?

Comment: a "line of best fit" is a specific, well-known statistical concept. It creates a straight line across the chart based on the actual values, to demonstrate the general trajectory. I'm asking if that's what you're trying to create, or are you inventing your own version? It's not clear what your actual underlying purpose is, beyond the coding question. I think people don't want to help you create something which is statistically invalid and would mis-represent the data. So it depends on what your actual intention and requirements are.

Comment: Whatever you used to calculate the second and fourth array to be different, use that but in javascript to calculate between points...

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/q/29532147/1447675 helps a bit.

Comment: @ADyson, the point of it, is that I already have the values in an array, but they can't be altered, at this point what is needed is just to normalize all values, so that there is no jump between each of the values, this is to show a straight line going up, because in some cases one point is way lower than the other. so it is just a matter of lowering the distance between each value of the array, that's all. Lets just not get into detail of the chart or statistical concepts, what I need right now is for the values to be similiar enough to create a straight line going up.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanksthat is actually something similar to what I need, but I was thinking is there a easier function javascript way to do this?

Comment: I used different values so that the example is clearer.

Comment: yes....but that's pretty much what the formal algorithm for a line of best fit does.  So maybe you ought to be using that, but without knowing your intention I can't definitely suggest it. That's why I'm asking you what you mean by "normalise" the line, and what it is supposed to represent afterwards (i.e. what should the person reading the graph be able to understand from that line)?

Comment: @ADyson that's not relevant, you can just ignore the whole graph line algorithm part, lets just say with the values given above, how can you achieve that?

Comment: @Leo, you changed the question a bit, now you need to move the value to a different range while keeping the relative distance, right? if so please add the range, or is it between zero and one?

Comment: It can be negatives, the point of it is just to keep the relative distance from numbers regarding the amount or the negative or no negative numbers.

Comment: @Leo you said you never want it to go down... well `0.6, 0, 1` wouldn't **0.6** to **0** be going lower/down...

Answer (score 3):

To get normalized value in the interval [0, 1], you could use the following by first getting min and max values and then adjust every value.

The result is an array with values between zero and one, which keeps relative distances.

```js
var array = [1, -2, 3],
    min = Math.min(...array),
    max = Math.max(...array),
    result = array.map(a => (a - min) / (max - min));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Well yeah that works ! But that returns numbers between 0 and 1, and I need it to return it with the maximum values and minimum values of the array, so for example lets make the array [900,1000,1800,2100] it should end up something like [700,1300,1700,2100], does that make sense?

Comment: it is quite unclear (for me), why do you start with `700` for the result. in which relation does it stand to the array which starts with `900`?

Comment: Yes that was an example, so lets say it is 700, 1300, the difference in that would be 600, from 1300 to 1700 the difference, is 400, and for the last one it is 400 too. The goal of the function or the "normalize" part, should grab those differences and make them closer to each other, for example instead of the differences being 600,400 and 400, the ideal would be that the differences are 465, 465, 470 ?

Comment: So at the end the values of the array should be changed, to match those differences closer together, does that makes sense ?

Comment: so the first difference is the starting point? and then add the average to every following item?

Comment: Well the first number will always be zero, from zero to above, would be to have the rest of the numbers reduce their value to match a more exact difference between them.

Comment: So for a more realistic examples lets say the values are:
[0,30,60,100,130,170,230,260,300,320];

That should end up something like:
[0,40,80,120,160,200,240,280,320,360];

Comment: ok, it starts with zero and you use a multiple of ten and you get a linear growing data set.